# asp.net mvc scripts.render serves _lahout.cshtml instead of actual script

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

on

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

I get a javascript error that shows what is suppose to be the content of jquery.js be actually what's inside is the content of my _layout.cshtml page.

Do you know why ?

**EDIT**

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery-ui").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.3.js"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery-validate").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js", 
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js", 
                "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include("~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js", "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
              "~/Content/bootstrap_spacelab.css", "~/Content/Site.css", "~/Content/themes/base/all.css"));
    }
}
```

Here is the content of the Scripts folder

- bootstrap-datepicker - Copier.js
- bootstrap-datepicker.js
- bootstrap-datepicker.min - Copier.js
- bootstrap-datepicker.min.js
- bootstrap.js
- bootstrap.min.js
- gridmvc.js
- gridmvc.lang.ru.js
- gridmvc.min.js
- home.js
- homeAbout.js
- homeDialog.js
- jquery-2.1.3.intellisense.js
- jquery-2.1.3.js
- jquery-2.1.3.min.js
- jquery-2.1.3.min.map
- jquery-ui-1.11.3.js
- jquery-ui-1.11.3.min.js
- jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js
- jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js
- jquery.validate-vsdoc.js
- jquery.validate.js
- jquery.validate.min.js
- jquery.validate.unobtrusive.bootstrap.js
- jquery.validate.unobtrusive.bootstrap.min.js
- jquery.validate.unobtrusive.bootstrap.min.js.map
- jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
- jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
- modernizr-2.6.2.js
- respond.js
- respond.min.js
- _references.js

Comment: make sure you have correct code in your bundle.config. and the path you have mentioned in your bundle.config are correct and files are located on those paths. can you share your bundle.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that I was trying to get Scripts from a folder without beeing authenticated. This cause a redirection from http://myurl.com/Scripts/jquery.js to http://myurl.com/Account/LogOn page which contain _layout.cshtml.

To solve the problem I edited web.config with the following :

```
  <location path="Scripts">
      <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
      </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="Content">
      <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
      </system.web>
    </location>
```

This way I can get access to scirpts without beeing authenticated